# Polar decomposition of a complex scalar field theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

In the text I am referring to, the field was substituted in terms of a number density and phase:
$$\psi(x) = \sqrt(ρ(x))e^{iθ(x)}.$$
While quantizing the field, a commutation relation was imposed:
$$[\theta(x, t), \rho(y, t)] = -i \delta^3(x-y).$$
How do we impose this relation?

Comment: Hint: Use the CCR for $\psi$ and $\psi^{\ast}$

Comment: Show that this reproduces the correct commutation relation between $\psi$ and it’s adjoint.